# Can ASN.1 *STRING field have zero length?

Tags: asn.1, der

Does ASN.1 standard allow UTF8String or PrintableString to have zero length? I've been looking for this information in ASN.1 specs but can't seem to find it.
I'm using DER encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

Consider following specification

```
Example DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= 
BEGIN
  Name ::= PrintableString                       
END
```

and following value

```
value Name::= ""
```

BER (and DER) encoding is

```
> ASN1STEP: Encoding of value notation  for PDU #1:
> 
> Encoding to the file 'data.ber' using BER encoding rule... Name
> PrintableString: tag = [UNIVERSAL 19] primitive; length = 0   ""
> Encoded successfully in 2 bytes: 1300
```

Tested on https://asn1.io/asn1playground/